# Why is Facebook Javascript SDK loaded asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, facebook, asynchronous, sdk

I am using the standard Facebook Javascript code in my Facebook app, which I got in my sample app on Heroku.  I don't really understand it, but by being careful I've been able to modify the sample app to do some basic things that are useful for me.

My understanding is that this code somehow loads the Facebook Javascript SDK.  That is, it loads a javascript code file.  What file is it really loading?  Why can't I just load it like I load any other javascript code file?  For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

The downside of this highly complicated approach is that I can't make heads or tails of it, and because I don't understand it, I have no intuition about how to use it.

Code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<?php echo AppInfo::appID(); ?>', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]; ?>/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true // parse XFBML
    });

    // Listen to the auth.login which will be called when the user logs in
    // using the Login button
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      // We want to reload the page now so PHP can read the cookie that the
      // Javascript SDK sat. But we don't want to use
      // window.location.reload() because if this is in a canvas there was a
      // post made to this page and a reload will trigger a message to the
      // user asking if they want to send data again.
      window.location = window.location;
    });

    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

It makes your site load faster because it doesn't need to wait for a response from the facebook server.

The window.fbAsyncInit is a callback and executes when the script is loaded.
So when the facebook server is down, this function never gets called.

When the api is loaded all functionality of the API is available. Just check the docs.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Why is it necessary to use this technique for the Facebook Javascript SDK when it isn't used for virtually any other Javascript code?

Comment: Facebook is one of the big players whose script gets embedded into millions of web pages, so they have to pay more attention to performance issues. And looking around I think you’ll find that other big players usually recommend embedding their scripts asynchronously too, f.e. Google, Twitter, …

Comment: And in the case of Facebook their servers can be slow at some moments. Just pay attention when a like button loads. There usually is a slight delay.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the replies.  I will take this to mean:  there is no other reason that performance, and it certainly could be loaded in the normal manner.

Comment: If you put it in the head yes. Your webpage will block until the facebook script is loaded. But if you put the script in the body, there is a chance that a function of the api will be used before the script is loaded and js will throw an error.

Comment: Why dont you test it yourself? try creating a new js file, say sync-facebook.js, and move the async fb code to it. Then require sync-facebook.js in your head.

Comment: Why not just download the script and serve it with the rest of your JS code? Minimized and unified to a single file. This will not increase your page's loading time much. Every such sdk script has a certain version and I doubt that FB goes back and makes changes to older versions.